# Font rendering issue (MAC vs Windows)

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, html-entities

I have a website in which I make use of the css @font-face declarations.
Then, in my html I use html-entities to display vector-images.

This works on all webbrowser on Mac (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera).
It also works on the same browsers in Windows (including IE9 +).

However, on the browsers in Windows, the icons have padding on top.

See my sreenshots (Chrome MAC vs Chrome Windows):

**Chrome MAC:**
[image: Chrome Mac]

**Chrome Windows:**
[image: Chrome Windows]

Do you guys know something that can fix this?

Comment: Please provide a toy example of your issue, so we can test and debug, e.g. on http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: @Cedric you can visit the page at beta.dimensus.nl

Comment: @Bram a JSFiddle link accompanied by code within your question is much better as when your problem is fixed your URL will be irrelevant to this question.

Comment: Ok, give me a minute. I'll make a JSFiddle :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem seemed to be in the Entypo font-file. The characters seemed to have different heights with unnecessary white space on top and bottom of a character.

The Mac did remove these white space, Windows didn't.

I found a new font-file that didn't have these problems. Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
.header #link_home_home a, .header #link_search a {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: block;
padding: 18px 20px 15px 20px;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
margin-top: 7px;
}
```

try  :

```
 .header #link_home_home a, .header #link_search a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 18px 20px 15px 20px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 7px;
    }
```

Padding is most probable to have different rendering. If that doesnt work and you want a cleaner solution you should use a css reset stylesheet above your css. Take a look here: http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-tips/css-tip-1-resetting-your-styles-with-css-reset/